# Retrieve multi selected value using Get and Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, get

I'm trying to read in values from a multi-select via get and javascript.

Here's an example of the string and values i'm trying to retrieve:

```
?q=y&deg[]=Graduate+Certificate&deg[]=Graduate+Degree
```

My code works with URLSearchParams in all browsers except late MS IE and early MS EDGE browsers.

Can someone suggest a way to read two separate values for deg[] without using a polyfill library?

Comment: If you want compatibility with older browsers that don't support it, then I'm confused how you don't want a polyfill. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-the-get-parameters

Comment: @zfrisch sorry. I saw that thread during my research and read it wrong.